# Shell script UI

Tags: bash, shell, user-interface, unix, manpage

Is there a way to display a simple text based UI via shell scripting that isn't interspersed with the prompts & etc in the main bash process? Essentially I want something that acts like `man`, only it displays something that isn't a manpage and waits for a user input to get back to whatever the bash process was displaying. Is there a way to do this just using an existing shell command or should I be doing this portion with a compiled language?

I know how I can get the user input and print stuff, but I'm unsure how to display said separate ui like `man` is doing.

Comment: Are you looking for the alternate screen? like: `tput smcup; printf '%s\n\n' "Hello world"; read -rep "press enter"; tput rmcup`?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf That actually seems like a slightly easier way to do it, now that you mention it, and I don't need to deal with redirecting input from within less to a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps `less` would be of use to you for this:

```
#!/bin/sh

displayfile="/etc/fstab"

printf "continuing with script 1\n"

sleep 1

less "$displayfile"

printf "continuing with script 2\n"

printf "continuing with script 3\n"
```

Answer (score 2):

See `dialog`, `kdialog`, `zenity`, and similar.

`man` can use any pager configured, the default today is usually `less`.